# PIL: Paste image with resized aspect ratio

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have 2 images (`icon.png` and `background.png`). In the `background.png` image, there is a blank area which will be the place for the `icon.png` to be pasted using PIL (Python). However, the `icon.png` is a little bit bigger compared to the blank frame in the `background.png`. How can I paste and make the `icon.png` smaller so it can fit with the frame?

My code so far:

```py
icon = Image.open("./icon.png")
background = Image.open("./background.png")

mask = Image.new("L", icon.size, 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
draw.ellipse((0, 0) + icon.size, fill=255)


back_im = background.copy()
back_im.paste(icon, (200, 100), mask=mask)
back_im.save("./back_im.png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use resize after read the icon image to fit the desired size:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

iconSize=(200,100)
icon = Image.open("./icon.png")
icon=icon.resize(iconSize)
background = Image.open("./background.png")

mask = Image.new("L", icon.size, 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
draw.ellipse((0, 0) + icon.size, fill=255)


back_im = background.copy()
# back_im.paste(icon, iconSize, mask=mask)
back_im.paste(icon, icon.size, mask=mask)
back_im.save("./back_im.png")
```